# How To Check Email Field For Duplicate/Existing Email Address Prior To Submitting Sign-Up Form

Tags: php, forms, email, email-validation, user-registration

Update: The email address check for the email field is returning "email address is already in use" upon entering an address regardless if the email address is new or exists in the mySQL database. I would like it to only return the error when an email exists in the email field of the users table in the database.

The current code for the signup page is:

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.js"></script> 
 <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>   
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function(){  
 $("#register").validate({
  errorElement: 'span',
  errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      if (element.attr("type") == "checkbox") {
          error.insertAfter($(".term"));
      } else {
    error.insertAfter(element);
      }
  },
  rules: {
      su_email  : { 
    required: true,
    email: true,
    remote: "/email_check.php"   
   },
      su_password  : { 
    minlength: 6, 
    required: true
   },
      su_conpassword : { 
    equalTo : "#su_password"
   },
      su_name   : { 
    minlength: 3, 
    required: true
   },
      su_phone  : { 
    required: true
   },
      su_city   : { 
    required: true
   },
      su_country  : {
    required: true
   },
      su_gender  : { 
    required: true 
   },
      su_quest  : { 
    required: true
   },
      su_ans   : { 
    required: true
   },
      su_terms  : { 
    required: true 
   }
  },
  messages: {     
   su_email: {
    required: "Please enter your email address",
    email: "Please enter a valid email address",
    remote: jQuery.validator.format("{0} is already in use")
   },
   su_password: {
    required: "Provide a password",
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
   },
    su_conpassword: {
    equalTo: "Repeat your password"    
   },
    su_name: {
    required: "Enter your full name",
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
   },
    su_phone: {
    required: "Enter your phone number"
   },
    su_city: {
    required: "Enter your city"      
   },
    su_country: {
    required: "Select your country"      
   },
    su_gender: {
    required: "Select your gender"      
   },
    su_quest: {
    required: "Select a security question"      
   }, 
    su_ans: {
    required: "Select a security answer"      
   },
    su_terms: {
    required: "You must agree to terms to join"      
   }
  }
 });
  
 $('.condition').click(function () { 
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#termscondition').dialog({
          modal: true,
          width: 600,
    buttons: {
     Ok: function() {
         $( this ).dialog('close');
     }              
    }
      });
  } else {
       $('#termscondition').dialog('close');
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

```html
<?php 
   include('includes/inc-public.php');
   include('includes/classes/class.user.php');
 $user = new User();
 $email = $_GET['su_email'];
 $valid = false;
 header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
 
 if(!is_null($email)){  
  $is_valid = $user->get_email($email);
  if($is_valid){
     echo json_encode($is_valid);
  }
    else{
   echo json_encode($valid);     
  }
   };
?>
```

[signup form when a new email address is being entered in the email field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDmd2.png)
[users table of mysql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mt2K.jpg)

Comment: This is not possible with a server side language, you will need some client side as javascript

Comment: I am using the jscript from jquery.validate.js if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: this is the screenshot from when an existing email address is being entered in the email field  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1bTP.jpg

Comment: is the remote: "/email_check.php" file in a subfolder of the jquery file? what is output of the $is_valid can you check this.

Comment: @dumb_moron the "/email_check.php" file is on the public_html/ path of my server which is the root where my index and signup pages are. the output of $is_valid is "public function get_email($email)
  {  
   $this->sql = "SELECT 'vemail' FROM 'wmldir_users' WHERE vemail ='".$email."'";   
   $this->data = $this->fetch_row_assoc($this->sql);
   if(!empty($this->data))
    return $this->data; 
   else{
    return false; 
   }  
  }" which is set in my class.user.php file

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/):

The serverside response must be a JSON string that must be "true" for valid elements, and can be "false", undefined, or null for invalid elements, using the default error message. If the serverside response is a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead", this string will be displayed as a custom error message in place of the default.

So you need to change your is_valid to true.

Comment: by changing the is_valid to true you mean from this line of code "public function get_email($email)
  {  
   $this->sql = "SELECT 'vemail' FROM 'wmldir_users' WHERE vemail ='".$email."'";   
   $this->data = $this->fetch_row_assoc($this->sql);
   if(!empty($this->data))
    return $this->data; 
   else{
    return false; 
   }  
  }
" ?

Comment: Yes instead of returning $this->data return true Else the validation will not work

Comment: I changed it to true now I get false when I enter any email address whether it is new or exists in the mysql database

Comment: Ok can You echo the $is_valid variable

Comment: so instead of returning $this->data return true I should echo the $is_valid variable, or am I doing so in conjunction with returning true?

Comment: don't know is this the plugin u are using http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: yes it is the plugin i am using...it checks and validates every field on my signup form properly except for the email address field